# How to get files from broken directory?

Tags: files, filesystems, directory, data-recovery

I created some files and directories on external NTFS HDD using Ubuntu. Some folders displayed with cross sign, I changes permissions for them (777), now they just as a files. Copying of directory didn't help. What can I do in this situation ? May be recover everything with some tool ?

Comment: Cross-posted on AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/735783/how-to-get-files-from-broken-directory

Comment: @dr01 Looks like that post was deleted

Answer (score 1):

1. You could try using Windows program to check this device for errors.
2. You could try using [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) program if files are lost on this drive.